# Java ROBOT producing error in Excel

Tags: java

I am looping through a column in excel and looking for unique values then saving them to an array:

```
    String[] centers = new String[30];

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.delay(5000);

           robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);


    robot.delay(1000);


    //Scroll Down Column
    for(int i=2; i<5428; i++){
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
        robot.delay(5);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN );
        robot.delay(5);

    //Copy Tile
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.delay(5);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.delay(5);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL );

    //Get Content of Tile
        String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
            .getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); 

    robot.delay(100);

    //Check if tile value is in array
    for(int l=0;l<30;l++){
        if(centers[l]!=(data)){
            centers[l]=data;
        }

    }

    //End of Scrolling through column
    }

    //print out whatever diffrent tile content variables it found
    for(int l=0;l<30;l++){
        if(centers[l].equals("")){}else{System.out.println(centers[l]);}

    }


    }





    }
```

The problem is after I copy the first tile a pop-up appears saying something like: error: clipboard contents cannot be emptied, other program using clipboard. What can I do so this can successfully scan an excel column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fix 1**

Release C key while copying the data.

```
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
```

---

**Fix 2**

Put some delay after the content is copied.

Excel may take some time to actually copy the data. It may be negligible for us, but it is not instant thing. Something like 25-50 ms should be enough for sure. You should test it to get exact minimum time

Hope this helps.
Good luck.